# Tkinter variable "Num1" referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new to Tkinter and don't know exactly what I'm doing. I have these two entry widgets which are both numbers when entered. Whenever I press the "run" button to multiply the numbers I get a "variable referenced before assignment error" and I'm not sure why.
Here's the code:

```
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    def myClick1():
        Num1 = int(Num1.get())
        Num2 = int(Num2.get())
        print(Num1 * Num2)
    Num1 = Entry(root, bg = "black", fg = "red", border = 10, justify = RIGHT)
    Num2 = Entry(root, bg = "black", fg = "blue", border = 10, justify = RIGHT)

    RAD2=Radiobutton(root, text = "Run", command = myClick1, fg = "red", bg = "black", border = 12)

    RAD2.pack()
    Num1.pack()
    Num2.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Num1` and `Num2` are assigned to within `myClick1()`, therefore they are considered local variables - completely unrelated to the global variables with the same names.  It would be simplest if you chose separate names for the Entries, and the results of calling `.get()` on the Entries.

Comment: Tried changing the variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, global variables such as `Num1` and `Num2` are available globally, as the name implies. However, if you try to assign a new value to a variable in a function, that variable automatically becomes local.

Thus, when you do `Num1 = int(Num1.get())`, `Num1` is considered to be a local variable. And since you have not assigned a local variable named `Num1` prior to this statement, `Num1.get()` fails.

If you rename the local variable `Num1` and `Num2` to something else, this will work.

```
def myClick1():
    num1 = int(Num1.get())
    num2 = int(Num2.get())
    print(num1 * num2)
```